# Projection of quasi projective variety is proper (or finite, or closed)

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-space

I'm trying to prove that variety $$X=\{(A,C,B)\vert AC=CA=BC=CB=0, \text{rk}(C)\leq1, \det(A)=\det(B)=0\}$$ is irreducible. Here $C$ considered up to multiplication by constant i.e. projectivisation of variety of matrices with rank $\leq 1$.

I want to apply irreducibility criteria from Vakil's note.
So I need to show that projection map $$\text{Mat}_{n\times n}\times \mathbb{P}(\text{Mat}_{n\times n})\times \text{Mat}_{n\times n}\longrightarrow \mathbb{P}(\text{Mat}_{n\times n})$$ projecting $(A,C,B)\longrightarrow C$ is of proper type. Alternatively I need to show that this map is finite, hence proper. Another book states that this map should be closed. But i haven't come up with any idea yet.

Probably useful: $f$ is of proper type iff $f$ can be decomposed to closed embedding and projection $X\longrightarrow P\times Y \longrightarrow Y$. I have projection, so probably should do something with closed embedding of matrices.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the answer I was looking for.
Consider $\mathbb{P}(\text{Mat}_{n\times n}\times \text{Mat}_{n\times n})\times \mathbb{P}(\text{Mat}_{n\times n})$. Given equations defines projective variety in this space. And now projection is a map from projective variety hence proper. Which means that projective variety is irreducible. Our initial variety $X$ (X is quasi projective as variety in product of affine and projective spaces) is an open subset of irreducible variety hence irreducible by [Irreducibility of an Affine Variety and its Projective Closure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/184213/irreducibility-of-an-affine-variety-and-its-projective-closure).